# Is this an efficient way of mapping with Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Im trying to map the list of Products and CategoryPictures properties inside the Category entity.

Then im mapping the Picture object inside the CategoryPictures.

Im not sure if this an effiecient way of using dapper as its my first time working with dapper. I used to work with entityframework.

Im using Dapper instead of EF as i want to improve my sql skills.

Should i use multiple results instead?

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetCategoriesListAsync()
    {
        using (var conn = SqlConnection())
        {
            string sql = @"select c.*, cp.*, pd.*, p.*
                        from Categories c 
                        inner join CategoryPictures cp on cp.CategoryId = c.Id 
                        inner join Products pd on pd.CategoryId = c.Id
                        inner join Pictures p on p.Id = cp.PictureId";



            //string sqlmulti = $@"select * from {tableName};
            //                   select * from Products";

            //List<Category> cat = null;
            //List<Product> prod = null;


            //using (var lists = conn.QueryMultiple(sqlmulti))
            //{
            //    cat = lists.Read<Category>().ToList();
            //    prod = lists.Read<Product>().ToList();
            //}

            var lookup = new List<Category>();

            await conn.QueryAsync<Category, CategoryPicture, Product, Picture, Category>(sql,
                                        (c, cp, pd, p) =>
                                        {
                                            if (lookup.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == c.Id) == null)
                                            {
                                                lookup.Add(c);
                                            }

                                            c.CategoryPictures.AsList().Add(cp);
                                            c.Products.AsList().Add(pd);
                                            foreach (var item in c.CategoryPictures)
                                            {
                                                item.Picture = p;
                                            }

                                            return null;
                                        });
            return lookup;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Change the _list<Category> to a _dictionary<int,Category>_ this will improve a lot searching for the id of an existing category

Comment: For that many tables with a `Select *` (which you should avoid anyway), yes I would use multiple resultsets and map using dictionaries. Bear in mind that Dapper doesn't like multiple columns with the same names

Comment: @Charlieface, Wouldn't i still have to use the Select * for multiple resultsets? Or do i have to specify every column for multiple resultsets?

Comment: You can do `select *` but it's not advised. It's best to specify columns explicitly, and only pull out the columns you need (otherwise you put excess load on the server).

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the link between Category and Product where the Product was child of Category.

The problem i was having with the previous code was that the Picture child of CategoryPictures was not populating properly. So i set the Picture object of CategoryPicture before populating CategoryPicture.

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetAllCategories()
    {
        using (var conn = SqlConnection())
        {

            string sql = @"select c.Id, c.Name, c.Description, c.Created, c.LastModified,
                               cp.Id, cp.CategoryId, cp.PictureId, 
                               p.Id, p.Url
                        from Categories c 
                        inner join CategoryPictures cp on cp.CategoryId = c.Id
                        inner join Pictures p on p.Id = cp.PictureId";

            var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Category>();
            await conn.QueryAsync<Category, CategoryPicture, Picture, Category>(sql,
                                   (c, cp, p) =>
                                   {
                                       if (!lookup.TryGetValue(c.Id, out Category found))
                                       {
                                           lookup.Add(c.Id, found = c);
                                       }

                                       cp.Picture = p;

                                       found.CategoryPictures.AsList().Add(cp);


                                       return null;
                                   });

            return lookup.Values.ToList();

        }
    }
```